# Load File in XAP

Tags: silverlight

I had a number of CSV files embedded within a Silverlight DLL (as Resource).  I need to move these into the XAP (as Content rather than resource).  The trouble is Application.GetResourceStream always seems to return null when I try and access the files.  I have tried a number of ways to achieve this but can't seem to do it.  How do you reference the CSV files from code behind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to Get Files From Resources in Silverlight 2.0](http://www.silverlightexamples.net/post/How-to-Get-Files-From-Resources-in-Silverlight-20.aspx)

> StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
>
> BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
>
> bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

Comment: Perfect.  The slash at the start was my issue.

Comment: Fancy seeing you here, Justin - I always screw the slash up as well. +1 is obligatory!

Comment: +1 for helping me. To read text file... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bf03a7fe-f697-48d3-9226-d67c4e66fa8a